# INotifyPropertyChanged, System.ObjectModel error in ASP.NET site using MVVMLight 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm-light

I just tried to update an ASP.NET 4.5 site that I had running against the pre-5.0 version of MVVMLight (4.4.32.1 nuget package) to use 5.0.2.

Now everything compiles fine in visual studio but I get an error on the first page view. It is essentially this:

> CS0012: The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

And it occurs at the time of compilation of one of my views:

```
public class _Page_Views_Account_Development_cshtml : 
             MyNamespace.Web.Views.BaseView<IEnumerable<MyNamespace.Data.Models.User>> {
```

Here's the detailed compiler output:

```
c:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f7cc8ed7\c7cafde5\App_Web_development.cshtml.5f83eb8c.uumj7lsy.0.cs(34,18): error CS0012: The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
c:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f7cc8ed7\c7cafde5\assembly\dl3\e7e549bd\cb383382_bafecf01\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f7cc8ed7\c7cafde5\assembly\dl3\031e1123\6f936e46_8202d001\MyNamespace.Core.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
c:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f7cc8ed7\c7cafde5\assembly\dl3\625906e6\c7417347_8202d001\MyNamespace.Data.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
```

The project hierarchy is essentially:

- "Web" References "Core" and "Data"
- "Data" References "Core"
- All three projects reference MVVMLight 5.0 "Libraries Only" nuget package.

All three projects target .NET Framework 4.5.2.

The interesting thing is that `System.ObjectModel` doesn't really seem to exist/work. Its not listed in Assemblies or Extensions tabs when I try to add a reference through Visual Studio. I can go dig it up in the Facades folder of the Reference Assemblies, but that assembly only contains `TypeForwardedTo` assembly attributes for a bunch of things (including `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Further, adding that Facades assembly as a reference to my projects does not get rid of the error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the answer. ASP.NET handles Portable Class Libraries a little differently than other assemblies. Since MVVMLight 5.0 switched all of the "libraries only" nuget packages to be PCLs, this introduced me to the different ways ASP.NET handles PCLs whereas it wasn't a problem before.

I guess there's "compile time" (when you hit build in VS) and then there's "runtime compile time" (when you run the ASP.NET app and it compiles the views for the first time). The issue is with the latter.

In order to fix it, you need to add the reference in the web.config like so:

```
 <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        ...
        <add assembly="System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        ...
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

And then it will be available at the time that the webpages are compiled.

Comment: This doesn't work for my WPF application (app.config). I am having this same exact problem. Also, why are you using MVVM with ASP.NET? I have to ask.

Comment: I wouldn't think the above would be applicable to a WPF app - it's specifically the runtime parts of ASP.NET that were the issue here. I'm guessing your problem is something altogether different.
To answer your second question, the models were in a shared library used by both WPF and ASP.NET, and the models inherited INotifyPropertyChanged. It wasn't actually used in the ASP.NET app though. It's since been refactored to not use that, however.